# setonclicklistener for ImageView to change fragment does not work

Tags: java, android

I want that when I click on `ImageView` – with id `firstGame` – the screen will switch to another fragment, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
public class roadMap_fragment extends Fragment {

    ImageView firstGame;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_road_map,container,false);
        firstGame = rootView.findViewById(R.id.firstGame);
        firstGame.setClickable(true);
        firstGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) rootView.getContext();
                questionFragment questionFragment = new questionFragment();
                activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.framelayout,questionFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_road_map, container, false);
    }
}
```

I looked at some articles but couldn't fix it.

Comment: did you put a break point and check what happens in onClick?

Comment: Instead of `(AppCompatActivity) rootView.getContext();`, can you try `requireActivity();`

Comment: Add this  return rootView;

Remove this line 
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_road_map, container, false);

Comment: this code is trying to inflate 2 fragment_road_map view. And since you added click on first one, and return statement is returning another view instance. So click is not working..

Answer (score 0):

change this line :

```
activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.framelayout,questionFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

to :

```
activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout,questionFragment).commit();
```

or add this code to your fragment adapter :

```
Private Boolean loadFragment (Fragment fragment) {
    If (fragment != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment)
        .commit();
        Return true;
    }
    Return false;
}
```

and call it from your image on click listener